# Why char* can hold a single char in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

This might sound too crazy but I just had a thought. In C why

```
char *pc = 'H';      // single character
char *ps = "hello";  // a string
```

both are valid? I mean why a `char*` can hold/refer a character as well as a null terminated string?

Why there are no guard clause or compiler error generated for `*pc` as that `char*` is not holding a null terminated string?

I checked it in [Ideone](http://ideone.com/p6Dv82) and don't get any warning.

Comment: I don't think `char *pc = 'H'` does what you think.

Comment: If you tried `printf("%s", pc);`, very interesting things could happen. Likely either garbage output or a crash.

Comment: Listen to your warnings or turn up your warning level.

Comment: always use: `g++ -Wall`. It will help you spot runtime errors like the one your code probably causes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *pc = 'H';
```

The above statement defines `pc` of type `char *` which means it can hold the address of an object of type `char`. You are initializing it with the character `H` - a different type. Remember that a character literal is of type `int` and evaluates to its character code which in ASCII is `72`. So, the above statement is equivalent to

```
char *pc = 72;
```

This is an illegal operation and compiler should warn you about it (in gcc, use the flag `-Wall`). You should not directly assign an address to a pointer because you don't know if you have access to the memory address. You should use the `address of` operator `&` to get the address of an object and then assign it to a pointer.

```
char *ps = "hello";
```

In the above statement, the string literal evaluates to a pointer to its first element. This address is assigned to `ps` which is of the same type, i.e., `char *`. However, string literals  are read-only in `C` but are not `const` qualified (unlike in `C++`) and thus attempting to modify the string literal using the pointer `ps` would not result in compiler error but undefined behaviour and most likely program crash due to segfault. Therefore, you should define `ps` as a pointer to a const `object` -

```
const char *ps = "hello";
```

Answer (score 10):

It *can* hold a `char` because there is an implicit conversion from `char` to `char *` (via `int`), and because `sizeof(char *) >= sizeof(char)`. You *shouldn't* do this, though (technically it is undefined behavior because the literal numeric value of a character is not likely to be a valid pointer address to a `char` type).

And in many/most compilers, this *does* generate a warning:

```
$ gcc -otest test.c
test.c:5: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Answer (score 3):

In

```
char *pc = 'H';
```

`'H'` as an `int` will be casted to a `char *` and will be used to initialize `pc`, compiler should give a warning about this.

In

```
char *ps = "hello";
```

`"hello"` will evaluate to its base address, which will be used to initialize `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile the above lines of code using g++, I get the following warning:

```
test-12.c:1:12: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

The compiler is performing a few automatic casts to initialize `pc`.

`char` -> `int` -> `char*`.

One just have to pay attention to the compiler warnings to detect unusual operations like you are attempting.